# sequence with the ability for a bounded set?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

{$a_n$} sequence with the ability that $\forall$ k $\in \mathbb{N}$ the set $A_k = \{n\in \mathbb{N}: |a_n| \leq k\}$ is bounded
I have to prove that $1/a_n \to 0$

How exactly are these 2 connected I can't seem to wrap around my head over something to start with

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis I cant figure something out for now do you have any ideas where should I start?

Comment: Here's a hint. Start with an $\varepsilon > 0$ and find a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/k < \varepsilon$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis ok i can do that easily through archimedes , and then from the definition of convergent sequences i should probably get my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. We can find some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{k} < \varepsilon$. Now the set $A_k$ is bounded which means that for some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $|a_n| > k$ for all $n \geq n_0$. This implies that $|\frac{1}{a_n}| < \frac{1}{k} < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$. Since $\varepsilon$ was chosen arbitrarily we can conclude that $|\frac{1}{a_n}|$ and subsequently $\frac{1}{a_n}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Could you please explain how $|a_n|$ $>$ k ?

Comment: Since the set $A_k$ is bounded then there exists an upper bound $n_0$. This means that for $n > n_0$ $n$ cannot belong to $A_k$, therefore $|a_n| > k$.

Comment: thank you very much now it is a lot more clear. Thanks for letting me understand this problem!

Comment: Happy to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Fix some $\varepsilon >0$ and consider a neighborhood $B(0, \varepsilon)$ of $0$. Find some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{k}< \varepsilon.$ Now, consider the set $A_k:=\{n\in \mathbb{N}: |a_n|\leq k\}.$ By the given condition, $A_k$ is a bounded subset of natural number, i.e., $A_k$ is finite. This proves that the set $B_k:=\{n\in \mathbb{N}: \frac{1}{|a_n|}\geq \frac{1}{k}\}$ is finite. Consequently, for all $n\notin B$, the terms $\frac{1}{a_n}$ is contained in the neighborhood $B(0, \varepsilon)$ of $0$. In other words, after a finite stage, every term of the sequence $\{\frac{1}{a_n}\}$ contained in the neighborhood $B(0, \varepsilon)$ of $0$. Since $\varepsilon$ was chosen arbitrarily, this means $\frac{1}{a_n}\to 0$.